# How can you tell which sql driver(s) are installed using PHP?

Tags: php, sql, database, driver

Forgive me if there are duplicate question elsewhere, but I can't find the answer anywhere!

Is there a way in PHP to show all sql drivers that are installed?
For example check if I have oci, pdo, or mysqli on my webserver.

Comment: PHPinfo shows all code modules that are available http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: `<?php php_info(); ?>`

Comment: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[get_loaded_extensions()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php) will give you all the extensions installed:

```php
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
```

You can filter the PDO ones that start with `pdo_`:

```php
foreach (get_loaded_extensions() as $extension) {
    if (substr($extension, 0, 4) == 'pdo_') {
        echo $extension . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Which gives the following result on my machine:

```
pdo_sqlite
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
```

For the non-PDO extensions, you need to individually compare them against the list produced by `get_loaded_extensions()`, or query them using [extension_loaded()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php).

Comment: Aha! That is exactly what I'm looking for! Although phpinfo() does show all the sql drivers, it also shows a whole bunch of other information that I don't currently need. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can get the output of the function from shell using : `php -r "print_r(get_loaded_extensions());" | grep pdo_`. This will output the php config for CLI env though, you can load the apache config using the -c argument : `php -r "print_r(get_loaded_extensions());" -c /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini | grep pdo_`.